# LibGdx removing actor from table, then reorder

Tags: java, libgdx

Is there a easy way to remove a actor from a table and re order the table? without remaking the table?
When I remove a actor from a table it shows a blank space where the actor was

```
actorInsideTable.addListiner(new ClickListener(){
   @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            super.clicked(event, x, y);
            actorInsideTable.remove();
        }
});
```

Comment: I don't have an editor in front of me right now, so I'm only guessing... Does the table have a `pack()` method? If so, try executing it after removing the Actor.

Comment: @munyul yes it does, Thank you very much, if you put the answer below ill accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calling `remove()`, call the `pack()` method from the `Table` object.